# How to arrange images in LinkedIn after uploading to its Experience section

Tags: linkedin

As explained [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/34325/adding-editing-and-removing-media-work-samples-on-your-profile?lang=en) we can upload images to the `Experience` section of [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/) profile. But after the images are loaded (as shown [here](https://www.cio.com/article/2386117/consumer-technology/how-to-add-video--images-to-your-linkedin-profile.html)), if you want to rearrange/order them in certain order how would you do that?

For example if you upload three images as follows Img1, Img2, Img3, LinkedIn will display them as Img3, Img2, Img1. I could not find a way to re-arrange the order (e.g. Img2, Img1,Img3) except deleting all the images first and reload them in certain order but that process is cumbersome for a larger number of images as it requires you to re-enter title and description of each image.

Answer (score 9):

Change the date by resaving or editing the date on the image. It's a LIFO stack - last saved appears first on LinkedIn 2020.

Comment: This works. should be accepted. I can't believe a company as big as linkedin doesn't have a way to sort that or at least to make it clear.

Comment: Sure forcing it to arrange works. But most users just want the UI to aid them. 
Interesting that this is a nearly 4 yr old question.

Comment: It doesn't seem that LinkedIn allows one to edit the date any longer so as far as I know this answer is invalid and there's no way to do it other than to download and re-upload images

Answer (score 2):

Sort the image `names in ascending order`. Then select all the images and upload them. They'll appear according to the sorted names.

*Fixed worked as on: 30th April 2021*

Comment: As of 24th Feb 2023, saving in ascending order of name does not work. In order of datetime works.

Comment: Ascending name order works again (7th Jul 2023)